# How to use nested while loops

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, nested

I'm trying to make a function that uses a nested while loop that prints something like this.

```
ranges(5,2)

5
0 1 2 3 4
4
0 1 2 3
3
0 1 2
2
0 1
```

my code that i have so far looks like this

```
def ranges(high,low):
while high >= low:
    print(high)
    high = high - 1
    y = 0
    x = high
    while x > y:
        print (y, end = " ")
        y = y + 1
```

The output is like this

```
5
0 1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3
0 1 2
0
```

I'm pretty sure I missed up in calling the nested while loop because when i split up the code to just print 5,...,2 in a column it works and so does the code for printing the numbers in a row. Any help would be cool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `print("")` right after the while loop, and modify the condition of the while loop to `>=`:

```
def ranges(high,low):
    while high >= low:  # <-- change the condition otherwise you'll miss the last number in every line
        print(high)
        high = high - 1
        y = 0
        x = high
        while x >= y:
            print (y, end = " ")
            y = y + 1
        print("")  # <-- this

ranges(5, 2)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
5
0 1 2 3 4 
4
0 1 2 3 
3
0 1 2 
2
0 1
```